# Is it possible that I can open or configure ktor project in android studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, ktor

I want to open ktor project in android studio so is there any plugin available in android studio to open ktor project.

Thank you.

Comment: I have a similar problem, where i would like to setup simple Ktor server on my machine. What i realize and i hope i am not right about it, you can only use Ktor on Intellij IDEA ultimate edition. That piece of info can be read when you try download the recent plugin for Ktor. There are some earlier versions of plugins, but those are marked as obsolete. I am looking for a workaround, because i am learning and i currently can't pay 500 euros per year just to have some fun with Ktor

Comment: I want also learn ktor and finding a way that I can open it with Android studio so that i don't need to install intellji IDEA because android studio is also a cpu intensive software.

Answer (score 0):

There are not any plugins available that I know of. You can probably open the code files in android studio, but I would not recommend it, IntelliJ IDEA comes with various additional tools to help debug and run your ktor project.

Answer (score 0):

You should try IntelliJ IDEA and the [ktor](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16008-ktor?_gl=1%2A1kdqk55%2A_ga%2AODEwNjU3NS4xNjEwNjE5MTk0%2A_ga_VCMCSM1ZZ7%2AMTYzOTQ3NzI4Mi4xLjEuMTYzOTQ3NzMwMS4w) plug-in, which you can get from the [ktor website](https://ktor.io/).